# component won't receive updates from parent angularjs

Tags: angularjs, components

I'm trying to receive updates from the parent component (async update) however while the original $onInit receives data from the parent, any updates doesn't update the parent (comes back as undefined)

Any way to receive updates?

Child component:

```
import template from 'html-loader!./child.html'

export const childComponent = {
    template: template,
    require: {
        parentComponent: '^parentComponent'
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: class {

        constructor($scope) {
            this.option = null
            this.items = []
            this.$scope = $scope
        }

        static get $inject() {
            return ['$scope']
        }

        $onInit() {
            this.items = this.parentComponent.items
            // this.items doesn't get updated when this.parentComponent updates
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
<div ng-app="app">

    <div ng-controller="AppController as vm">
        <parent-component items="vm.fruit">
            <div ng-if="vm.fruit.length < 1">Loading...</div>
            <child-component></child-component>
        </parent-component>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem in the question itself. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The answer won't require more code, and the problem won't be able to reproduced unless I require extensive list of files. The data is passed across it just won't update so it's an angularjs knowledge problem requiring someone with prior knowledge of the framework and not javascript

Comment: Works fine in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/iy4mZXiAYkW56S0vCrpO?p=preview).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: @georgeawg you're embedding the component with the parent. I don't want to do that because the parent becomes dependant on the child component. Now I have more context I can deliver the difference - I have updated the question with the html

Comment: @Ruegen would you mind updating the plunkr code rather than updating the question. It would help us to directly play around with your code

Comment: [PLNKR demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/biGcd5Iii8bIcTPCnvpK) @ShashankVivek can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take a look at this demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xIaiYvAXLwnzNvtmr6rP?p=preview)

The reason, `$onInit()` was not getting called because, you need you need to add 2 things:

Add `transclude: true` in `parentComponent` declaration

and then add `ng-transclude` in html as below:

```
<parent-component ng-transclude>

  <child-component></child-component>

</parent-component>
```

---

Comment: Thank you @ShashankVivek that worked, I didn't know you could declare ng-transclude on the outside as I thought it was only in the template. Many thanks!